# What is a real world application of complex matrices?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, vectors, electromagnetism

During my CS undergrad I had 2 semesters of linear algebra, and I really enjoyed solving matrices; as I progressed further into my degree and my field, I realized that there are quite a few real-life applications of matrices in computer science specifically, for instance, in image processing and neural networks.
But all of the applications I've dealt with only involved real matrices. My sister who's in 11th grade asked me if there were any applications of complex matrices and I'm stumped. Are there any? I vaguely remember something about electromagnetism and complex matrices; but are there any real world uses of **complex matrices** that I could explain to a high schooler?

Comment: Quantum mechanics/computation.

Comment: if you want to stick to computer science and more precisely to image processing, the discrete fourier transform and the wavelet transform, which both use complex matrices

Comment: Also note that any complex number 
$a+bi$
[has an equivalent $2x2$ matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers)
$\displaystyle {\begin{bmatrix}\phantom{-}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}}$,
hence, complex $m\times n$ matrices can be handled 
as real $2m\times 2n$ matrices.